# How to enter the 3rd integer after the string

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main(){
        int a,d;
        char* name;
        name = malloc(sizeof(char*)*25);
        if(NULL == name){
                return 0;
        }
        scanf("%d",&a);
        scanf("%d",&d);
        gets(name);
        printf("\n %d : %s : %d \n",a,name,d);
        return 0;
}
```

### op:

```
1
de rt
```

I couldn't input the 3rd integer if I enter the string with spaces.

Comment: When preparing to fill a buffer with some variant data to form a string, it is a very good idea (and sometimes absolutely necessary) to pre-set the buffer with all '\0'  I.E. after the malloc, memset( name, '\0', 25);

Answer (score 4):

First, never use `gets` to read string. It is obsolete now. Use `fgets` instead.
Second, the `\n` character left behind by the `scanf` is read by the `gets` that's why you are not able to input the string. You need to flush your input buffer. It can be done as

```
scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%d",&d);
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)  
    ;
fgets(name, 25, stdin);
```

Also change

```
name = malloc(sizeof(char*)*25);
```

to

```
name = malloc(sizeof(char)*25);
```

or you can omit the `sizeof(char)` as it is equal to `1`

```
name = malloc(25);
```

Comment: And size in malloc should be: `sizeof(char) * 25 + 1` (`sizeof(char)` is Always 1 and may be omitted) not `sizeof(char*)*25`. Assuming the name input string is Always < 25

Comment: @TheMask; Yes. Agreed :). But I think it should be `name = malloc(sizeof(char)*25 + 1);`

Comment: The ip i gave was 1,2, rest less .But still with the changes made .. Its not printing the correct values

Comment: @TheMask `name = malloc(25);` and `fgets(name, 25, stdin);` is just fine.  No need to `+ 1` for these 2 functions to work well together.  May need `name = malloc(26);` and `fgets(name, 26, stdin);` since OP wanted to input up to 24 `char` via `gets()` and now will need 1 more space for the `'\n'`.

Comment: Note, if the buffer cannot fit the `\n` then the `\n` remains in the stream .

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //to standard

int main(){
    int a,d;
    char* name;
    name = malloc(100);//or simply char name[100];
    if(NULL == name){
        return 0;
    }
    scanf("%d", &a);//1st integer input
    scanf(" %99[^\n]", name);//input string with space
    scanf("%d", &d);//3rd integer
    printf("\n %d : %s : %d \n", a, name, d);
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```